# Multiple meanings for one variable?

Tags: variables, visual-basic-6

I'm replacing a guy who was in his first job as a programmer. You'd think being fresh out of school means the basics are fresh in one's mind, but think again.

The code base is horrible, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is apparent in lots of areas, about 60% of the logic is coded in forms and the rest is in a monstruous module called `helpers`. It hits the database in a `If` condition and re-hits the database with the exact same query inside the `Else` part. In general, it's as if declaring a variable had a higher cost than hitting the database or querying XML with an xPath.

Logic is scattered between stored procedures, table-valued functions (with an inexistent naming convention so you don't know if you're looking for a SP or a TVF) and inline SQL (string concatenations), and the seldom comment will just rephrase the code it's commenting.

Complex conditional logic is written in nested `If` blocks with a cyclomatic complexity that's just off the charts, in arrow-shaped procedures that can reach 1200 lines of code.

I can deal with all of the above... to a certain degree. But recently I came across something that just blew my mind.

The author was declaring a `String` variable with a meaningful name (call it `smurfName`), passed it to a table-valued function to get an integer value, and then used that integer value to determine another string value that gets used further down the process, here's a simplified illustration:

```
Dim smurfName As String
smurfName = (run some inline xPath on a IXMLDOMNode to get a string value)
...
smurfName = (call a helper to run inline SQL, pass smurfName as a parameter, returns a count)
If smurfName = 0 Then
    smurfName = "abc"
ElseIf smurfName > 1 Then
    smurfName = "def"
End If

smurfName = (call another SQL procedure, pass smurfName as a parameter)
```

And it just keeps going.

**Is reusing a variable (/giving it a new meaning) a common practice or it's just another "WTF" in that code base I'm stuck with? Is there any valid reason for doing that?** If not, then what drives a programmer to work like this? I'm a self-taught programmer, maybe this guy knows things that I don't (I didn't know about xPaths until I saw them in that code base), but when I tried understanding the meaning of that variable, this picture came to my mind:

[image: WTFs/Minute]

Comment: @pdr posted a good link. In short, that is generally a code smell. Reuse of variables generally means that items should be moved into smaller methods that stand alone. BTW, I like the cartoon. ;)